# Controller waiting even after using async and completable future

Tags: java, spring-boot, asynchronous, completable-future

I am developing a Spring Boot application where I want to make my controller asynchronous using CompletableFuture and the @Async annotation. To test the implementation, I intentionally added a Thread.sleep() call in the service method. However, even with these asynchronous approaches, the controller is still waiting for some time before executing. I have verified that my controller and service are running on different threads, as evidenced by their distinct thread IDs. I am unsure why this is happening, and I would appreciate any insights or suggestions on how to resolve this issue.

code is given below:

```
//controller
  @PostMapping
    public CompletableFuture<User> createUser(@RequestBody User user) {
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getId()+"-----------------------------------"+System.currentTimeMillis()+"----------"+"inside controller");
        return userService.createUser(user);
    }
```

// service

```
   @Override
    @Async("asyncExecutor")
    public CompletableFuture<User> createUser(User user) {
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getId()+"-----------------------------------"+System.currentTimeMillis()+"-------------inside services");
        return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() ->{
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000000000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getId());
           return userRepository.save(user);
        });
    }
```

It would be helpful to provide some code examples or specific details about your implementation in order to give a clearer understanding of the problem.

//output

```
21-----------------------------------1683404458540----------inside controller
34-----------------------------------1683404458543-------------inside services
2023-05-07 01:51:28.812  WARN 36119 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.web.context.request.async.AsyncRequestTimeoutException]
```

Comment: hi & welcome! i tried (not) to reproduce...(works like charm!) now see: (your exception message+) `Thread.sleep(1000000000);` that's *a lot of* (1 bill.) milliseconds! ... => 1 mill. seconds => ...it's about `11,5740741` days! (that's no good "testing time frame"!:)

Answer (score 1):

`Thread.sleep(1000000000);` seems too much for a (build) test ... That refers to ~ 12 (solar) days!

#### This works

- [starter](https://start.spring.io/#!type=maven-project&language=java&platformVersion=3.0.6&packaging=jar&jvmVersion=17&groupId=com.example&artifactId=demo&name=demo&description=Demo%20project%20for%20Spring%20Boot&packageName=com.example.demo&dependencies=web,lombok,devtools)
- "App":

  ```java
  package com.example.demo;

  import java.util.UUID;
  import java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture;
  import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

  import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
  import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
  import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
  import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
  import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.Async;
  import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.EnableAsync;
  import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
  import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
  import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
  import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
  import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;

  import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;

  @EnableAsync
  @SpringBootApplication
  public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
      SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Slf4j
    @Service
    static class MyAsyService {
      @Value("${simulation.sleep.seconds:10}")
      private Long simSeconds;

      @Async
      CompletableFuture<String> doSomething(String req) throws InterruptedException {
        log.info("in service...");
        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(simSeconds);
        log.info("...leaving service");
        return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(req + "_" + UUID.randomUUID());
      }
    }

    @Slf4j
    @Controller
    static class MyController {
      @Autowired
      MyAsyService service;

      @GetMapping("/hello")
      @ResponseBody
      CompletableFuture<String> hello(@RequestParam(required = false, defaultValue = "anonymous") String req)
          throws InterruptedException {
        log.info("in controller...");
        CompletableFuture<String> result = service.doSomething(req);
        log.info("...controller done!");
        return result;
      }
    }
  }
  ```
- in browser:
  [image: browser screenshot]
- in server logs:

  ```text
  ... o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet    : Completed initialization in 1 ms
  ... DemoApplication$MyController : in controller.... <= req#1
  ... DemoApplication$MyController : ....controller done!
  ... DemoApplication$MyAsyService : in service....
  ... DemoApplication$MyAsyService : ....leaving service
  ... DemoApplication$MyController : in controller.... <= req#2
  ... DemoApplication$MyController : ....controller done!
  ... DemoApplication$MyAsyService : in service....
  ... DemoApplication$MyAsyService : ....leaving service
  ... DemoApplication$MyController : in controller.... <= req#3
  ... DemoApplication$MyController : ....controller done!
  ... DemoApplication$MyAsyService : in service....
  ... DemoApplication$MyAsyService : ....leaving service
  ```
- (automatic, mock mvc) test (hardest part;):

  ```
  package com.example.demo;

  import static org.hamcrest.core.StringStartsWith.startsWith;
  import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders.*;
  import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.content;
  import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.request;
  import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.status;

  import java.util.UUID;

  import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
  import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
  import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
  import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcTest;
  import org.springframework.mock.web.MockHttpServletRequest;
  import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc;
  import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MvcResult;
  import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.RequestBuilder;

  @WebMvcTest
  class DemoApplicationTests {

    @Autowired
    MockMvc mockMvc;
    @Value("${simulation.sleep.seconds}") // -> src/test/resources/application.properties
    Long simSeconds;

    @Test
    void testController() throws Exception {
      String uid = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
      MvcResult mvcResult = mockMvc.perform(get("/hello?req={v}", uid)) //1.
          .andExpect(request().asyncStarted()) // 2.
          .andReturn(); // 3.

      mockMvc.perform(asyncDispatch(mvcResult/*, (simSeconds + 1) * 1000*/)) // 4!*
          .andExpectAll( // ...
              status().isOk(),
              content().string(startsWith(uid)));
    }
    // 4*: when we take/simulate more than ~10 seconds, we have to & can re-implement/enrich:
    static RequestBuilder asyncDispatch(MvcResult mvcResult, long timeToWait) {

        // copied/adopted from MockMvcRequestBuilders#asyncDispatch
        mvcResult.getAsyncResult(timeToWait);

        return servletContext -> {
            MockHttpServletRequest request = mvcResult.getRequest();
            request.setDispatcherType(DispatcherType.ASYNC);
            request.setAsyncStarted(false);
            return request;
        };
    }
  }
  ```

#### Thx To

- https://sadique.io/blog/2015/11/24/testing-async-responses-using-mockmvc/
- https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/web/servlet/request/MockMvcRequestBuilders.html#asyncDispatch(org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MvcResult)

---

Changing service to:

```
CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() ->{
  try { //...
```

..has no significant effect.